# ggplot2: adjust alpha of legend colors & reorder

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting two geom_line datasets with ggplot2.  Each has an accompanying geom_ribbon.  Each dataset is a different color that has been adjusted with a different alpha factor.  I want to:

1. Adjust the line color shown in the Legend to match the color of the geom_line for each sample.  From what I've read, adding `+ guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(alpha=c(0.7, 0.5))))` should accomplish this, but it is not working here.  Doesn't cause any errors but doesn't have the desired effect.
2. In the same Legend, use the ribbon color and alpha.  In the Legend, the gray line should be within a haze of lighter grey.  Repeat for red line.  Not sure how this would be done, as the data source for each geom_line & geom_ribbon are independent.
3. The order of in the Legend should match the factored order (versicolor then setosa).  I am stumped as to why this isn't working: the factor order is correct everywhere I check.

For simplicity, I am working with the iris dataset and mimicked my workflow.  My dataset is more complex and is the reason why I define the colors before making the plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

samples <- data.frame(
  Species_Number=c(2,1),
  Species=c("setosa", "versicolor")
  )

samples <- samples %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Species = factor(Species, levels=c("versicolor", "setosa")))

df1 <- iris %>%
  dplyr::filter(Species=="setosa") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Position=1:50) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Species1_Sepal = Sepal.Width) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Species1_Error = abs(Sepal.Width - mean(Sepal.Width))) %>%
  dplyr::select(Position, Species1_Sepal, Species1_Error)

df2 <- iris %>%
  dplyr::filter(Species=="versicolor") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Position=1:50) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Species2_Sepal = Sepal.Width) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Species2_Error = abs(Sepal.Width - mean(Sepal.Width))) %>%
  dplyr::select(Position, Species2_Sepal, Species2_Error)

df_final <- df1 %>%
  dplyr::left_join(df2, by = c("Position" = "Position"))

Species1 <- samples$Species[samples$Species_Number==1]
Species2 <- samples$Species[samples$Species_Number==2]

colorscale <- c("#333333", "red")
names(colorscale) <- c(Species1, Species2)
LegendTitle <- "Species"

Plotv1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df_final, aes(x=Position, y=Species1_Sepal, col = Species1), linewidth = .75, alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_ribbon(data = df_final, aes(x=Position, ymax=Species1_Sepal+Species1_Error, ymin=Species1_Sepal-Species1_Error, fill = Species1), linewidth = 1.2, alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_line(data = df_final, aes(x=Position, y=Species2_Sepal, col = Species2), linewidth = .75, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_ribbon(data = df_final, aes(x=Position, ymax=Species2_Sepal+Species1_Error, ymin=Species2_Sepal-Species1_Error-0.2, fill = Species2), linewidth = 1.2, alpha = 0.25) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colorscale) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colorscale) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(title=LegendTitle)) +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

```
#Check Factor Order
> str(samples)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Species_Number: num  2 1
 $ Species       : Factor w/ 2 levels "versicolor","setosa": 2 1

> Species1
[1] versicolor
Levels: versicolor setosa

> Species2
[1] setosa
Levels: versicolor setosa

> names(colorscale)
[1] "versicolor" "setosa"
```

[image: Plotv1]

Answer (score 0):

I would change philosophy towards common ggplot2 way. Please try this code with minimum changes in comparison to your code instead:

```
df <- iris %>% 
  mutate(Species = factor(Species, ordered = T, levels = c("versicolor", "setosa"))) %>% # force order of factor
  filter(!is.na(Species)) %>%  # filter "versicolor", "setosa" only
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(Position = 1:50) # assign numbers as in your code


colorscale <- c(adjustcolor("#333333", 0.7), adjustcolor("red", 0.5)) # note that they overlap thus making colors darker
fillscale <- c(adjustcolor("#333333", 0.25), adjustcolor("red", 0.25))
names(colorscale) <- c("versicolor", "setosa")
names(fillscale) <- c("versicolor", "setosa")
LegendTitle <- "Species"


ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Position, y=Sepal.Width, col = Species), linewidth = .75) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=Position, ymax=Sepal.Width+0.2, ymin=Sepal.Width-0.2, fill = Species), linewidth = 1.2) + 
    # these geoms should not be plotted twice in this case
  scale_fill_manual(values = fillscale, name = LegendTitle) +
    # assigning same name to scales forces them to combine
  scale_color_manual(values = colorscale, name = LegendTitle)
```

[image]

Comment: My data frame is 5 columns: Position, Species1_SepalWidth, Species2_SepalWidth,  Species1_Error, Species2_Error, and for each species, the  ribbon is `ymix= Species1_SepalWidth-Species1_Error, ymax=Species1_SepalWidth+Species1_Error` - repeated for Species2.  I will restructure the data in my question, as I'm not sure how to achieve what you've done starting with my format.

Comment: @JVGen I think it is not fair to change rules on the way. I spent my time to answer the previous edition of the question with three questions actually in one. If you need to reshape the data and don't know how to do this it is a matter for another question

Comment: To be fair, you did restructure the data originating from iris for your answer to be functional, and I did warn that I had used the iris dataset for simplicity.  I can't restructure my original data in the way that you've shown.  I am trying to learn how to reshape my data with `tidyr::pivot_longer()` but I am having trouble.